# Sidebar mini cart not updating totals and quantity

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, ajax, onepage-checkout

I have a problem with the sidebar mini cart not updating in my Magento store. I think it is something to do with Ajaxt/Javascript request to the checkout progress wrapper but I am not entirely sure and would like to seek clarification from my fellow Magento Devs.

The template I am using has been heavily customised but the mini cart does update when the page is refreshed, I would like it to update as a product is added to the shopping cart if possible.

Here's my code for sidebar.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
    <div class="block block-cart">
    <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Cart Summary') ?></span></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">   

    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?> 
     <?php $numberItems=count($_items); ?>
            <?php $i=1?>    
            <?php if (count($_items)): ?>
        <!--        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>-->
                <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
                       <li <?php if($i==$numberItems): echo "class='last'";endif;?>>

                            <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()); ?>
                            <?php
                            if ($product->getTypeId() == "bundle") {?>

                                <?php if($product['type_id']=='bundle'):?>
                <?php  $val=Mage::getModel('bundle/product_type')->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct()); ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php foreach ($val as $getone):?>
            <?php  $bundle_option_arr = $getone['bundle_option'];
                break; ?>
            <?php endforeach ;?>
            <?php foreach ($val['bundle_options'] as $_optionval) : ?>
            <?php  $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_optionval);
                      $optId=$this->htmlEscape($_optionval['option_id']) ?> 
                <?php foreach($_optionval['value'] as $option): ?>
                    <?php  $_formatedOptionValue1 = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($option); ?>  
             <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php $mystring = implode('-',$bundle_option_arr[$optId]); 
             'bundle option = '.$mystring;
            ?>
                         <?php       $count = count($bundle_option_arr[$optId]);
                            } else {

                                $count = 1;
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="checkout-product-listing">
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(36,36);?>"/>
                               <!-- <img class="image" src="<?php e//cho Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . "catalog/product" . $product->getThumbnail() ?>" />-->
                                <div class="product-details">
                                    <span class="product-name"><?php echo $product->getName() ?></span>
                     <?php 
                    if($count >1):
                    $itemMessage=" items, ";
                    else:
                    $itemMessage=" item, ";
                    endif;
                    ?>  
                                    <div class="item-qty"><span class="product-count"><?php echo $this->__($count.$itemMessage).Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getPrice()) ?></span><span class="qty-span"><?php echo $this->__('x' . $_item->getQty()) ?></span></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
     <?php $i++;?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
    <?php echo $this->getChildhtml('totals')?> 
                <?php else: ?>
                <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildhtml('three-payment')?>
        </div>


    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And my opcheckout.js Which updates the progress wrapper. I think I am missing the appropriate div id in the mini cart so would like to ask for any to clarify if possible please...

```
reloadProgressBlock: function(){
    //var updater = new Ajax.Updater('checkout-progress-wrapper', this.progressUrl, {method: 'get', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this)});
    var updater = new Ajax.Updater('checkout-progress-wrapper', this.progressUrl, {method: 'get', onComplete: function(){ajaxcart.updateMinicartEvent();},      onFailure:this.ajaxFailure.bind(this)});
},
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you call "mini cart"?

Comment: @Tim Sorry, Cart Sidebar...

Comment: but it has no relation to the checkout process. maybe i understand your question wrong.

Comment: @Tim I have created a module which adds an additional step in the accordion checkout where I upsell additional products. Customer can click "Yes add to cart" OR "No thanks!" before proceeding to the next step. If a product is added I need to update the sidebar cart on the fly without refreshing the page to avoid having the customer re-enter billing info...

Comment: @user1704524 without seeing what goes on in `ajaxcart.updateMinicartEvent();` and possibly the controller action that it calls, I doubt we will be able to help you here

Comment: I think this should be reopened - it's a valid and common question for Magento's Onepage checkout, and this question has more detail than many others I have seen on this forum - worth of an answer at least.